# Azure function throws error while running with UseDevelopmentStorage = true

Tags: azure, function, azure-functions

The Listener for function '' was unable to start.

> Microsoft.WindowAzureStorage : An error occurred while sending the
> reqeust.System.Net.Http : An error occurred while sending the request.
> System.Private.CoreLib : Unable to read data from the transport
> connection : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
> host...An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Answer (score 0):

The setting UseDevelopmentStorage = true looks for the port number 10000/10001 and 10002 for the Blob, Queue and Table.

But if these ports are being used by some other service then we are not able to use local storage emulator for the azure function.

1. check the port being used by which service using - resource monitor - type resmon in cmd prompt and go to listening port section.

In my case grafan service was using this port.

2. Go to Services - type services.msc in cmd prompt. and go and stop the service. In my case i stopped the Grafana service.
3. Restart the storage emulator again. Check the status it is using the port 10001  ports

This will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually run the azure emulator before running my app.  See [THIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio) article.  I opened a command prompt and ran:

```
"c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\Azure Storage Emulator\azurite.exe"
```